# Make the regex find any word that contains at least one lower case letter

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How to fix this regex so it finds any word that contains at least one lower case letter `grep -E -e '^[S][a-z]+, [^S][a-z]+' People.txt`.
The regex I am using know is to search for the second name that stars with capital S followed by comma and then space and then the first name that starts with any letter other than S. I want to fix this regex so it can also find a name like this`SbBBB, PaUU`. **I am using grep in the terminal of MacBook**

Smith(second name)
Paul(first name)

**Text file**

```
Smith, Paul
SbBBB, PaUU
Pau, Smi
Smi, Smi
SA, PA
```

**The output of the regex**

```
Smith, Paul
SbBBB, PaUU
```

Comment: Are you saying that your regular expression is matching the line `SbBBB, PaUU`?

Comment: Also, what do you call an *alphabetic character*? `[a-z]` matches a lot of characters (such as `⒜`, `⅍`) which I wouldn't consider "alphabetic". And there are a lot of characters that I would call alphabetic (such the Greek letters which gave their name to the *alphabet* word or the uppercase Latin letters) which it doesn't match.

Comment: It is my bad, I fixed the question. What I need is to fix the regex so it doesn't accept special characters and numbers.

Comment: As far as I can see, that regex doesn't accept special characters or numbers, other than as the first letter after the comma, but you don't have any in that position in the input. Of course there could be such characters later in the line, after the part the RE matches, but that's slightly different. So what is it exactly that you're trying to do, and what you're trying to have the RE match?

Comment: I think I need to edit the question again because I got confused while writing the question question what I need exactly was to find any name that starts with s and the second name doesn't start with and must contain at least one lower case letter and it can contain upper case letter but at least one lower case letter.

Comment: I think something you need to clarify is whether this is an exercise in getting a single regex *just so* or to show that you can use `grep` to filter a list.  A *just so* regex is going to be complicated and hard to read.  Filtering with multiple `grep` commands in a pipeline will be a lot more straightforward to create and read.

Comment: I am supposed to use regex in finding the results.I just don't want to use a lot in grep.

Comment: To match a single lowercase character (in any alphabetic script that does have such a concept of case), use `[[:lower:]]`. Or `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` to specify exactly which ones you want to match.

Comment: Please add any and all requirements to the question.

Comment: @bxm I fixed the question

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any POSIX compliant `grep` and assuming you want to match English language upper case letters other than `S` for the start of the second word:

```
$ grep '^S[[:alpha:]]*[[:lower:]][[:alpha:]]*, [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ][[:alpha:]]*[[:lower:]][[:alpha:]]*' file
Smith, Paul
SbBBB, PaUU
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -Px 'S\pL*\p{Ll}\pL*, (?!S)\p{Lu}\pL*\p{Ll}\pL*' < your-file
Smith, Paul
SbBBB, PaUU
```

Would report lines that start with `S` followed by any number of *letters* (characters with `L`etter `p`roperty), followed by 1 lower case letter, followed by any number of *letters* followed by `", "`, and an uppercase letter other than `S` and again a number of letters, at least one of which lower case.

PCRE `\pL`, like POSIX `[[:alpha:]]` is not limited to letters in alphabetic scripts; that includes word characters of any script. You could replace with `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}]` to only match on letters that can be considered either lower or upper case or with `\p{Latin}` for any letter in the *Latin* script (as used in English, French, Spanish...) and `(?=\p{Latin})\p{Ll}` for a lower case letter in the Latin script only (not those in Greek, Cyrillic, etc scripts) for instance.

To use those `[a-z]` and only match on the 26 lowercase letters of the US ASCII charset, you'd need to fix the locale to `C`/`POSIX` and then you don't even need PCRE:

```
L='[A-Za-z]' Ll='[a-z]'
LC_ALL=C grep -x "S$L*$Ll$L*, [A-RT-Z]$L*$Ll$L*"
```

Note that it won't match on `Serra, Éric` for instance as that `É` is not matched by `[A-RT-Z]` in the C locale.